# Align background image with a an image with HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

First time on stackoverflow, also my first time with HTML and CSS.

Basically I want a transparent image to be kind of "hooked" on to one specific point on the background, i.e. if I resize the browser window, the image should maintain its position relative to the background and should get smaller accordingly.

The reason I need this is because the image is animated and positioned to a certain spot on the background.

The easiest way I could show it is by actually showing it so: [www.opinionoto.com](http://opinionoto.com)

As you can see I want the speech bubble to always be right beside her face and maintain its position no matter what device or browser size.

This would be great help for me, I'm a super begginer! Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

why not use multiple background images and position the second one accordingly where ever you need it?

Comment: I thought about that but then I cannot animate the image because it is an div block that I'm animating

Answer (score 0):

Does the bubble move after the initial move? Can you just make the background a GIF image?

Comment: No it doesn't move after the initial move. I'm afraid a GIF animated image would be far too ineffecient in terms of speed and size

Comment: What about using Taran's suggestion, and using your script to change the background positioning instead of moving a DIV?